# How do review sites backlink to review blogs?

Tags: blog

I have discovered several review sites that link to blog reviews on the same subject.

How do these review sites get their links and can this be done programmatically?

- One example is [this site](http://malaysiamostwanted.com/venues/tenji-japanese-buffet-sohokl) (Look under Bloggers' Review).
- Another example is [urbanspoon.com](http://urbanspoon.com/r/9/1601393/restaurant/Atlanta/No-246-Decatur) which also has Blogger Review
  section.

Comment: Could you provided some examples so we can better understand your question?

Comment: Hi, One example is this site http://food.malaysiamostwanted.com/venues/tenji-japanese-buffet-sohokl Look under Bloggers' Review. Another example is http://www.urbanspoon.com/r/9/1601393/restaurant/Atlanta/No-246-Decatur which also has Blogger Review

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, they're just searching for blog posts that contain the name of the restaurant in the title.

In the second case, the bloggers are members of the review site, and they include a badge from the site that links to the review site's page on that restaurant.